# Group by using inner property in a list using Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list that contain following type of objects

```
public class A {

    public List<B> B {get;set;}

}
```

The `B class` state as follows.

```
public class B {

    public List <C> C { get;set;}
}
```

The `C class` state as follows.

```
public class C { 

    public int Id { get ; set ;}
    public string Name  { get; set;} 
}
```

Can someone point me how can I group above list by `Name` property in `C` class.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Name and how many time same name repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results = a.SelectMany(a1 => a1.B.SelectMany(b1 => b1.C)
              .GroupBy(g => g.Name)
              .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }));
```

It should return a list of objects containing a `Name` property for each unique name found, along with a `Count` property specifying how many of that `Name` were grouped.

The nested calls to `SelectMany` will flatten the object hierarchy, the `GroupBy` will create the grouping on the `Name` property. Finally, a new anonymous type List is returned though the `Select` and is populated with properties from the group, with `g.Key` being the value the grouping was based on (`C.Name`).

A Fiddle can be found [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrTkAG) (Provided by @chadalavada harish)